# SQLAlchemy connect through specific network interface

Tags: python, linux, windows, networking, sqlalchemy

I have a client computer (now Windows 10, soon to be Ubuntu Server) connected through a LAN Ethernet interface to a remote DB server using SQLAlchemy. The same client holds a Wifi network interface connected to Internet in order to provide external access to the client. Within the client there is a Python script that runs reading the remote DB Server and updating a local DB with records of interest.

Everything works fine while the Wifi interface is disconnected, and SQLAlchemy's `engine.connect()` throws a connection error when the Wifi becomes active.

The question is how to force the connection to be done through the Ethernet interface for the following commands:

```
engine = create_engine(url)
engine.connect()
```

I am expecting some sort of default routing configuration for the SQLAlchemy engine, or a workaround that does not involve SQLAlchemy.

Comment: I don't think you can solve the problem in SQLAlchemy, you need to address it in the machine's nerworking config.